# Using 12v to power two 6v coil relay in series

Tags: relay

FTR-J2AK006W (https://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fcai/relays/ftr-j2.pdf) has two 6v coil inside it, does this mean I can connect them in series and feed them 12v?

Comment: See page 3 of your datasheet, the second table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, because what matters is the current through the coils and by putting them in series 12V would produce the same current as 6V through one coil.

Comment: This is not always true, check the datasheet.  Some relays actually do have two ratings, pull-in, and holding.  Those have a circuit that drastically reduces the power through the relay when it is actually energized.

Comment: You are correct, however, for his relay this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Read page 4 (coil nominal voltage), and page 7 (Circuit) of your data sheet.
It's said we can use either series or parallel configuration and nominal voltage of series become twice of single coil. the answer is yes. Please read datasheet more carefully.